# Send File to my website

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I am trying to send a file through FTP in VB.NET.

I have 3 labels with the server password and user information and a textbox with the file location called `txtFile` and my `Textbox 1` has the new file name.

I click send and it doesn't come up in my website?

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(txtFile.Text, 
                               ServLabel.Text & TextBox1.Text, 
                               PassLabel.Text, 
                               UserLabel.Text)
```

Comment: Do you recieve any errors?

Comment: No.. Just doesn't send..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfkdh7eb(v=vs.90).aspx

You have your Username and Password swapped;

```
Public Sub UploadFile( _
   ByVal sourceFileName As String, _
   ByVal address As String, _
   ByVal userName As String, _
   ByVal password As String _
)
```

and should be doing;

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(txtFile.Text, 
                               ServLabel.Text & TextBox1.Text, 
                               UserLabel.Text,
                               PassLabel.Text)
```

Also, make sure you have the necessary Path Separators between your Server Address, and the file name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the FtpWebRequest class. Here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("testfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
                    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```